# Get value of an array key=>value based on value of another key=>value?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have to keys, 'payment_date' and 'balance'. I have a function that checks 'payment_date' to see if it's <= 'today', and it works but now I don't know how to fetch 'balance' from that:

```
function getCurrentBalance($myTable){
    $today = new DateTime('now');
    $today = $today->format('Y-m-d');
    foreach($myTable as $row) {
         foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
                 if ($key == "payment_date" && $value <= $today){

                 }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be $row <= $today

Comment: @TusharGupta: $row is an array...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really don't need the second loop, if you already know the keys you need. You can access them directly.

```
function getCurrentBalance($myTable){
    $today = new DateTime('now');
    $today = $today->format('Y-m-d');
    foreach($myTable as $row) {
         if ($row['payment_date'] <= $today){
             //Do something with $row['balance']
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm just learning about arrays and this makes sense now. I don't know if this is the correct place to ask but my array has many dates so it's possible that <= $today will return multiple results. Is there a way to specify that only the last result be returned? I.e. I have August 1, Sept 1. With the above, both August 1 and Sept 1 are returned. I only want Sept 1.

Comment: @Ash Yes, with [array_pop()](http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) you'll get the last value.

Comment: Thank you Charlotte, but will this return the last result up to <= $today?

Comment: What do you mean by "last result up to <= $today"? array_pop() will just return the last element (and pops it out of the array) of the specified array, nothing more.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, <=$ today can return multiple results but I would just like the one closest to <= $today. I don't think array_pop() is right for this.

Comment: Do you mean `$today` or `$row['payment_date']`? Because `<= $today` is nothing but a comparison.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I'm using the right terminology. The comparison <= $today (Sept 12) can return multiple results of $row['payment_date']: August 1, Sept 1. In a month from now, it'll return August 1, Sept 1, Oct 1. Is there a way to retrieve $row['balance'] for the last date (Oct 1)?

Comment: You can still use array_pop, but you have to sort the array first. http://3v4l.org/hKtlY

Answer (score 0):

do it like this instead:

```
foreach($myTable as $row) 
{
    if ($row['payment_date'] <= $today)
    {
        echo $row['balance'];                        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well what do you want to do, I think that your answer is:

```
function getCurrentBalance($myTable){
    $today = new DateTime('now');
    $today = $today->format('Y-m-d');
    foreach($myTable as $row) {
        foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
            if ($key == "payment_date" && $value <= $today){
                $balance = $row['balance'];
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```